# Центрирование главного окна

Tags: qt, qt6

Linux, Qt 6.6
Необходимо отцентрировать главное окно приложения.

Использую следующий код в main:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
DPSMainWindow w;
// w.size.width = 800 w.size.height = 600

QPoint center = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()->geometry().center();
//Center.x = 959 Center.y = 539
int x = center.x() - (w.width()/2);                                     
int y = center.y() - (w.height()/2);                                    

center.setX(x);
center.setY(y);
// Center.x = 559 Center.y = 239
    
w.show();
w.move(center);

return a.exec();
```

окно не центрируется.

В чем могут быть проблемы?

Answer (score 0):

Вы не учитываете рамку окна и не учитываете уменьшенную рабочую область экрана.

```
//Геометрия с учётом панели задач
QPoint center = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen()->availableGeometry().center(); 

w.show();

//Геометрия с учётом рамки окна
QRect frame = w.frameGeometry(); 
int x = center.x() - (frame.width()/2);
int y = center.y() - (frame.height()/2);

center.setX(x);
center.setY(y);

w.move(center);
```

Здесь `show()` вызван до расчёта местоположения т.к. до вызова данного метода рамки окна не существует.

Comment: вот вывод при Вашем варианте

top.w.x = 0 top.w.y = 0
Center.x = 959 Center.y = 539
w.size.width = 800 w.size.height = 600
on show top.w.x = 0 top.w.y = 0
Center.x = 556 Center.y = 223
on move top.w.x = 559 top.w.y = 253
on move pos.w.x = 556 pos.w.y = 223

Что, по большому счету, соответствует моему.
Но! Окно  остается на месте, а координаты его верхней левой точки соответствуют выше указанным!

Почему окно не перемещается в эти координаты?

Comment: top = w.mapToGlobal(QPoint(0,0));

std::cout << "on move top.w.x = " << top.x() << " top.w.y = " << top.y() << std::endl;

Comment: top = w.pos();
 std::cout << "on move pos.w.x = " << top.x() << " pos.w.y = " << top.y() << std::endl;

Comment: `top = w.mapToGlobal(QPoint(0,0));` Даёт вам глобальную координату точки, которая находится под заголовком окна, справа от рамки (т.е. на самом виджете). `pos()` даёт координату с учётом рамки. Соответственно разница это левая рамка окна и заголовок.

Comment: @КонстантинФомин, или вы хотите сказать что окно остаётся в координатах (0,0)?

Comment: да именно так. не совсем на нуле, но и не на середине экрана

Comment: А если заменить`DPSMainWindow w;` на `QMainWindow w; w.setMinimumSize(800, 600);` эффект будет аналогичный?

Comment: проверил под виндой - центрируется. под Linux - нет

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/application-windows.html#wayland-peculiarities Попробуйте `w.windowHandle()->startSystemMove();` после обычного `w.move(center);`

Comment: не помогает :-(